bash: what's the difference between '< file' and taking input from a here-string which contains the file?
I have a variable foo_var which contains ASCII text (base64 text, with some additional text which includes dashes, spaces, and underscores). I write this var to a file as follows:
cat <<<"$foo_var" > foo_file

I have a program which reads from stdin (openssl). This invocation works, with an exit code of 0:
$ openssl rsa -passin stdin -pubout < foo_file

but both these fail, with a message saying that stdin can't be read, and an exit code of 1:
$ openssl rsa -passin stdin -pubout <<<"$foo_var"
$ echo "$foo_var" | openssl -passin stdin -pubout

What's the difference between these cases? The obvious answer is that parameter expansion occurred in the failing case, but this can't be right, because the same parameter expansion would have happened when foo_file was created. I'm on bash 5.1.16.
EDIT
Added the args, as requested. However, there's a complication - the args ask for both a password and a private key on stdin. This relies on what seems to be an undocumented openssl feature, which is that a single input stream can be used for both, but the password must be on the first line, followed by the key. So, it's not trivial to repeat. If anyone really wants a go I'll post a working password/key file.
EDIT2
I've done some debug by running under strace. For both the working and failing cases, there's some (essentially identical) initial setup, and then a read request is made on stdin, for 4K bytes. This returns 1887 (the number of bytes actually available), and therefore advances the file position to 1887. In both cases, openssl then attempts an lseek (lseek 0, -1875, SEEK_CUR)). For the failing case, this fails with an ESPIPE, as you might expect, and the program terminates soon after. For the passing case (redirection from an actual file) lseek succeeds, returning a new file position of 12.
Ok, so nobody expects stdin to be seekable. But bash sets up everything in both cases, and in both cases openssl sees only stdin. It can seek in one case and not the other. But openssl knows that the input is stdin, because that's a command-line parameter, so why does it seek at all??
Conclusion? (A) Input redirection from a file and a here string are not equivalent, because Linux somehow makes seeking possible in the first case, or (B) openssl has messed up by attempting the lseek, and is taking advantage of a bug/feature? In any event, it should never have attempted the lseek, because it already knew what the data was.

Can you show the full openssl command? Just so that we can test directly with it. (And rule out any unrelated issue.) Anyway, a difference between the two is that input from a pipe can't be seeked, so if openssl tries to do that (for whatever reason), it won't work.

(Also openssl has several subcommands, there might be differences between them)

I think you pretty much answered your question here with what you discovered. Openssl wouldn't need to seek if it just bothered to remember what it had read. But, it might be that it's just two unrelated routines within the program conflicting with each other somewhat. If there's one utility function that reads a line and seeks back to the line end, and another that reads something else, but no connection between them, no common buffer, then that's what you get. Of course that's exactly what stdio is for, but I'm not at all surprised if openssl doesn't use that...

And, well, stdin is just a file descriptor. There's nothing that would make stdin as such non-seekable: if it's connected to a file, seeks work fine. And if not, then not. Also, I would expect the internals of openssl don't really if it was stdin this time, or some input that was given to openssl as a filename and it opened itself. After all, once you have the fd, it's just an fd you can read from.

Going by your explanation, there's a chance you could get away with using a process substitution to avoid writing to an actual file: openssl rsa -passin stdin -pubout < <(printf '%s' "$foo_var"). Maybe. I'm not sure.

(Sorry, I didn't get around to testing the command myself, even though I asked about it. I'm not that familiar with openssl rsa, and was too tired to think right now.)

@kos, process substitution creates a pipe too, just not on stdin. (Or a socket, but that's pipe-like enough.) In Zsh, one could use =(printf...) to have it create a temp file, but if the idea was to avoid temp files... Having the two pieces of data get passed through two different fds should avoid the issue.

@kos: I have actually tried that, but no luck. I'm just about to try running the script from C++, rather than directly on a terminal, and I suspect that will work. The lseek man page says "On Linux, using lseek() on a terminal device fails with the error ESPIPE."

@ilkkachu I thought so, but I don't remember if there are nuances to reading from a file descriptor that would make it slightly different from reading straight from a pipe, if they're exactly the same then yeah, I tried :)

@QF0:  I don’t understand what you’re thinking, but I doubt that your experiment will work.   You’re not currently seeking on the terminal.   The fact that you’re invoking the command by typing it (into the shell) in a terminal is irrelevant.

Are you saying that it only occurs with some passphrase? I can't seem to reproduce the problem: https://paste.debian.net/plain/1318137

Hi @TomYan: very interesting - doesn't work for me. I've generated a new key with openssl genpkey -quiet -algorithm RSA -aes-128-cbc -pass pass:meh > test. I've then run all 6 of your tests. The first 3 pass, as expected, but the next 3 fail, with Could not read private key from <stdin>. So this seems to be system-specific. I'm on Ubuntu 22.04, kernel 6.5.0, OpenSSL 3.0.2, bash 5.1.16.

When one reads the most recent manual on openssl (openssl v3.3 man1 openssl-rsa
) (and know a bit about the background of openssl), one can see that openssl assumes your keys to reside in files.
With that assumption it is perfectly understandable it assumes it can lseek(2) in there.
It can seek when you use openssl  < filename because the shell will open the file, fork(2), move the open file descriptor to position 1, and then exec openssl. So, when openssl wakes up it has the file at descriptor 1.
On the other hand when you use echo "foobar" | openssl or use a here document, the shell sets up openssl with a pipe(2) for it's file descriptor 1, and you can not seek in pipes (or sockets or ttys, or...).
Now you could argue that that is an omission, but I doubt you can convince the openssl maintainers that keys should be flying around in pipes and sockets in stead of being safely stored in files.
@ilkkachu is probably right that the function reading the password is probably way over in another module from the place where the key reader is. But you could of course find out yourself (openssl is open source)
As a side note: many Unix/Linux commands behave slightly differently when their stdin is a file or a tty or a pipe etc. In C this is accomplished by checking the result of fstat(2).
Your frustration if I may call it that, seems to stem from the misconception that "stdin" is a kind of file. It is not. "stdin" only says that the file is at index one of the process file table. It says nothing about the type of file and it's features.
I'm sorry but that's just how it is.

I'm not frustrated, and "everything" in Linux is a "file". I'm merely pointing out inconsistencies in what, on the face of it, appear to be the same usage of stdin and asking if there was a bash explanation. The comment from @TomYan demonstrates that what I expected does actually happen on certain systems.

@QFO I'm sorry, you write "Ok, so nobody expects stdin to be seekable.". This is wrong. Seeking does not depend on whether a file "is stdin". "is stdin" means the file is at index 1 in the process file table.  Lseek(2) depends on the file type. One can seek in " regular" files and in "character device files".  One can not lseek(2) in a file of type pipe, socket, or fifo. (see https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Testing-File-Type.html for an explanation of a way to establish file type in C, and https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html for an explanation on lseek(2))

@QFO I did some of TomYan's test and they work on my system too. I'm running openssl version "OpenSSL 3.3.0 9 Apr 2024"
Apparently the openssl team decided it is not necessary to seek at all to get the two pieces of input, and fixed it between openssl versions 3.0 and 3.3.
This has nothing to do with shells or input redirection or "stdin". This is about a program using lseek(2) and you not giving it a regular file.
